# AFHTTPSessionManager.h showing file not found in singleton class?

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking-2

I am trying to create a singleton class for AFNetworking 2.0. I installed through cocoa pods in iOS-8.0.But i am always getting an error like AFHTTPSessionManager.h file not found on that particular file only. even if i included #import .But its working fine for the view controller classes that are already present  in the project . I am using

> http://blog.christophertao.com/singleton-afnetworking/

tutorial for reference 
Can anybody help me to find out where i am going wrong?